# Why doesn't DOMXPath work?

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

I've been trying to write a PHP script to parse an XML document using [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php); however it seems I'm missing something because none of my XPath queries are returning anything. So I've tried to water down my script to try and parse a very rudimentary XML document, and that's not working either. I've based this script off of [this XPath example](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_examples.asp).

```
<?php

$xml  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
$xml .= '<bookstore>';
$xml .= '<book category="COOKING">';
$xml .= '<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>';
$xml .= '<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>';
$xml .= '<year>2005</year>';
$xml .= '<price>30.00</price>';
$xml .= '</book>';
$xml .= '</bookstore>';

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query('/bookstore/book[1]/title');
var_dump($result);

?>
```

Problem is that my var_dump of $result *always* returns something like:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#4 (0) { }
```

...indicating that it found nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the output of var_dump() is misleading.
Try

```
foreach($result as $e) {
  echo $e->nodeValue;
}
```

or

```
echo $result->length;
```

instead.

e.g. using your code (up until $result = $xpath....) +

```
echo phpversion(), "\n";
var_dump($result);
echo $result->length, "\n";
foreach($result as $e) {
  echo $e->nodeValue;
}
```

the output is

```
5.3.1
object(DOMNodeList)#4 (0) {
}
1
Everyday Italian
```

Comment: Whoops. My mistake was assuming that var_dump would show me something. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with a doc that specifies xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" in the root node. Took it out, and xpath works.